# center background image in IE

Tags: css

So bless my heart... I figured out how to center the body background image via CSS3 and the background:cover element.

FF and Chrome look great... and it seems to size properly regarless of browser window size.

IE however, still causing me acid reflux...

I have tried to use the

```css
filter:progID:DXImageTransform:Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progID:DXImageTransform:Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But it does not seem to be working...

Am I missing something?

here is the CSS:

```css
body{
     background:url(../images/background.jpg);
     -webkit-background-size:cover;
     -moz-background-size:cover;
     -o-background-size:cover;
     background-size:cover;
    filter:progID:DXImageTransform:Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progID:DXImageTransform:Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use MS filters, the src inside the filter is relative to the page I think, not the CSS file. Try using this instead:

```
src="/images/background.jpg"
```

or set the path to something relative to the page.

Comment: Well the image is dispalying, however it its displaying as if i was just calling it as a regular backgrond image... i tried removing the ".." in the URL pat, and then tried removing the slash "../" in the image path... no luck.

Comment: It's hard to know why without seeing it in action. Try just using one filter at a time? The MS filter actually covers over the content in the element also - so it may not be suitable for use as a site background image.